# How can I rotate the screen in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I was implementing a camera preview and I allowed three kinds of device orientation showed as the picture below.

[image]

I created a UIViewController class and in it the code generated automatically.

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}


override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }

}
```

However, the effect now looks like:

[image]

How should I do to implement rotation in right way?

Comment: maybe the orientation-support is correct, but the constraints have not set up correctly to adopt the new layout...

Comment: Agreed. The point is how can I set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:
At the bottom of your storyboard there is a section for setting constraints. On the left side of that section are different devices that can be viewed as well as portrait and landscape orientation. Try selecting landscape to see how your image view appears. Then you can adjust the constraints as you wish.